# What difference between C++ std::mutex and windows CreateMutex

Tags: multithreading, c++11, multiprocessing, mutex

I'm programming in Windows on c++ (Visual Studio)
I can create mutex using either std::mutex or CreateMutex.
What is the difference between them? Which one I should prefer and which one is faster? Do they have any specifics in usage or implimintation? or maybe std::mutex is just a shell and uses CreateMutex inside?

Comment: CreateMutex is a Win32 api function, while std::mutex is from C++ standard library. You can use CreateMutex instead of std::mutex, but the code will not be portable from Windows to Unix.

Comment: One is system independent and portable, the other is not. And it's not unlikely that `std::mutex` is a wrapper using the native Windows mutex primitives under the hood.

Answer (score 6):

Besides the fact that std::mutex is cross platform and CreateMutex is not another difference is that the WinAPI mutexes (created through CreateMutex) can be used for synchronization between different processes, while std::mutex can not be used for that. In that sense std::mutex is more equal to the WinAPI Critical Section.

However there are also other things to consider, e.g. if you need to interoperate with std::condition_variable's or with WinAPI events (e.g. in order to use WaitForMultipleObjects).

Comment: Maybe std::mutex uses WinAPI Critical Section instead of CreateMutex inside? As I know Critical Section is much faster.

Comment: According to benchmarks reported at [A Windows mutex is not a mutex](http://www.sevangelatos.com/a-windows-mutex-is-not-a-mutex/), `std::mutex` is significantly faster than `CreateMutex` as a thread synchronization primitive.

Answer (score 3):

`std::mutex` is provided by the C++ standard library and yes, most probably it will call `CreateMutex` under the hood.

Since `CreateMutex` is not portable, `std::mutex` is generally preferred.

Comment: Also `std::mutex` isn't interprocess

Answer (score 2):

A difference in behavior is that `CreateMutex` under Windows creates a recursive mutex, while `std::mutex` is a non-recursive one. You'd have to use `std::recursive_mutex` that was also added in C++11.